trouble loading a previously saved mobilev2net based model
I have created an image classifier model based on MobileV2Net , trained it and saved it properly. when i try to load a previously saved model i constantly getting this error:
**The Error:**

`/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
184         if spec.ndim is not None and not spec.allow_last_axis_squeeze:
185             if ndim != spec.ndim:
--> 186                 raise ValueError(
187                     f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
188                     "is incompatible with the layer: "
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "global_average_pooling2d_7" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (512,)
`
my code is :
`loaded_test_model=tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/testsave/modeltest.keras')`

